# Google Spreadsheet: Count for multiple criteria

Tags: function, google-sheets, spreadsheet

> K     T
>
> WW   Data
>
> 34    1
>
> 34    3
>
> 34    4
>
> 35    2
>
> 35    5
>
> 36    1
>
> 36    0

How to count number of jobs where DATA>3 for WW=34?

I have tried on several methods but all doesn't work in Google spreadsheet.
method 1: `=counta(iferror(filter(T:T;TRIM(T:T)>"3";TRIM(K:K)="34")))`

method 2: `=ArrayFormula(sum((K:K="34")*(T:T>"3")))`

method 3: `=ArrayFormula(sum(if(K:K="34",if(T:T>"3")))`

method 4: `=count(filter(T:T;T:T>"3";K:K="34"))`

method 5: `=iferror(index(query(K:T,"select count(T) where T>'3' AND K='34'"),2,1),"")`

But all doesn't work...
Anyone can help??

Comment: Do the columns are of type: text or number?

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand what you need to count, perhaps the following formulas can help you.

Columns number:

```
=QUERY(K:T; "SELECT COUNT(T) WHERE K = 34 AND T > 3 LABEL COUNT(T) ''")
```

You can also use a function like this:

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(T:T; VALUE(K:K) = 34; VALUE(T:T) > 3); ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to data types!

Numbers/characters that are surrounded by single/double quotation marks, such as `"3"` and `'3'` are string literals, so `T>"3"` compares the value in `T` to the **string** `"3"`, not the number `3`.

Therefore, when you want to compare number values, you need to make sure that both your data and the value used for comparison are *numbers* at the time the actual comparison takes place.

The conversion may be done implicitly by the parser for some data types, (try `=NOW()*2` :), or explicitly by you, either because you know the data type is not a number, or you take some sort of precaution with regards to the column's (unknown) data type, like using the `VALUE()` function, (as suggested by @wchiquito).

Remarks:

- Some formats can "break" the `VALUE()` function as well, making it necessary to take further precautions... but this is beyond the scope of the current discussion.
- When you import data from other applications, a column of *normal* or *number* values may be converted to *string* type by either the exporting or the importing application.